# Finding what Numbers can be Produced Mod k

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So I have a big number, say 107279. Now, I want to take all of its multiples mod $10^9+7$. How do I determine which integers mod $10^9+7$ are of such a form, $107279k$? I did some searching and fiddling, and came up with nothing particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, suppose you have a number $d$ (which stands in for $107279$ in your example) and another number $k$ (which represents $10^9+7$), and you want to know which residues can be produced by taking multiples of $d$ modulo $k$.

The general answer is that you first compute $g = \gcd(d,k)$, and then there will be exactly $k/g$ possible residues, specifically all of the multiples of $g$ modulo $k$: $0, g, 2g, \ldots, k-g$.  In this particular case $g=1$ and so there will be exactly $k$ possible residues, namely all of them.

This is a very elementary consequence of the simple yet powerful [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $10^9+7$ is a prime number.

Hence $107279^{-1} \mod (10^9+7)$ exists

Hence we can always solve for $107279 x \equiv y \mod (10^9 +7)$ for any $y$.

Hence $y$ can take any value from $0$ to $10^9+6$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}{\bf Hint}\quad  &a\mid x\!\!\!\pmod{\!n}\\[.3em]
\iff\ &\exists\, j\!:\ x\equiv ja\!\!\!\pmod{\! n}\\[.3em]
\iff\ &\exists\, j,k\!:\ x = ja+kn\\[.3em]
\iff\ &\gcd(a,n)\mid x
\end{align}$

i.e. $\ a\Bbb Z + n\Bbb Z= \gcd(a,n)\Bbb Z\ $ by Bezout.

Answer (score 0):

they have a GCD of one so all integers mod $10^9+7$ appear.